# How to deal with table name with [ ] square brackets inside?

Tags: sql-server, escaping

My code issues SQL queries to SQL Server like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM [db_name].[schema_name].[table_name];
```

This worked until it failed on a customer table named `SLOT_APRX[NOT USED]`. Note the `[` and `]` inside the table name.

What is the proper, safer way to escape table names in SQL Server then?

Comment: np, I just tested with SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON and it works both in table creation and in select. Make sure it is ON like in @ne1410s answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the `]`, just like you would a `'` in a literal string: `[SLOT_APRX[NOT USED]]]`:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.[SLOT_APRX[NOT USED]]];
```

Ideally, however, you shouldn't have object names that require to be delimit identified (and escaped), and that avoids problems like this.

Comment: I don't see any escaping here. This is what my code sends now, and fails (except you have three `]` but only two `[`).

Comment: @user124114 There are 3 `]` at the end. the first `]` escapes the second, and the last is the quote delimiter. You need to escape the `[`, only the `]` characters. So a object called "My [Silly Named] Table" would be passed as `My [Silly Named]] Table]`.

Comment: Oh OK, wow. So your suggestion is to double any `]` characters inside the table name?

Comment: If you're ever unsure of the correct way to escape the name, you can use `QUOTENAME` to find out: `PRINT QUOTENAME(N'SLOT_APRX[NOT USED]')` returns `[SLOT_APRX[NOT USED]]]` for example.

Comment: I'm saying do it exactly as you would with a `'` in a string, @user124114 , yes. For the literal string `Mc'Donald` it would be `'Mc''Donald'`. For an object `My [Table] Name` it would be `[My [Table]] Name]`.

Comment: Seems to work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b322b78220ee2388239458668186ed4a . Thanks!

Comment: But, like I said, ideally don't have object names you need to delimit identify **and** escape, @user124114 . Some applications don't properly quote their object names, so having a `]` can be a big breaking problem.

Comment: Yeah, but that choice is not mine.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the Quoted Identifier setting can come to your rescue..

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM "SLOT_APRX[NOT USED]"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Can you add a full example? Including the database and schema part, as in the question.

Comment: I'm not really a fan of this, as it relies on the connection settings, or the setting being set it the statement. Some applications don't use `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` for their connections. Escaping the characters, however, will always work.